# Custom UICollectionViewCell self size according to the label text

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a UICollectionViewCell xib and would like the cell to adjust automatically according to the length of the label text like the picture shown below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN4Ua.png]

The picture shows what I made on a prototype cell. But no matter how I tried, the cell just kept the same size when I used a xib instead.

Answer (score 0):

implement this delegate UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let market = self.markets[indexPath.row]
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text =  market
        label.sizeToFit()
        return CGSize(width: label.frame.width, height: 25)
    }
```

or

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let text = NSAttributedString(string: markets[indexPath.row])
        return CGSize(width: text.size().width, height: 25)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just implement this in sizeForItemAt
just insert 'yourString' and 'yourFont':

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = yourString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: yourFont]).width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 20) 
}
```

you might need to add some space to the width because of the corner radius of the cell